# How to register IViewComponentDescriptorProvider in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, simple-injector

I have set up my dependency injection using **SimpleInjector** in the same way as presented [here](http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/aspnetintegration.html). Unfortunately, calling `RegisterMvcViewComponents` on the container object throws an exception:

> No service for type
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewComponents.IViewComponentDescriptorProvider'
>   has been registered.

Does the container have a corresponding method for registering the provider? Or should it be done in some other way?

The code:

```
public class Startup
{
    private Container _container = new Container();

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.InitializeTestData();

        services.AddMvcCore();

        services.AddSingleton<IControllerActivator>(new SimpleInjectorControllerActivator(_container));
        services.AddSingleton<IViewComponentActivator>(new SimpleInjectorViewComponentActivator(_container));           
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseSimpleInjectorAspNetRequestScoping(_container);
        _container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new AspNetRequestLifestyle();
        InitializeContainer(app);
        _container.Verify();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
            );
        });
    }

    private void InitializeContainer(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        _container.RegisterMvcControllers(app);
        _container.RegisterMvcViewComponents(app);

        _container.Register<IDbContext>(() => new DbContext("GuitarProject"));
        _container.Register<IJournalEntryRepository, JournalEntryRepository>();
    }
}
```

Stack trace (the type of exception is `InvalidOperationException`):

> at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider
>   provider, Type serviceType)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider
>   provider)    at
>   SimpleInjector.SimpleInjectorAspNetCoreMvcIntegrationExtensions.RegisterMvcViewComponents(Container
>   container, IApplicationBuilder applicationBuilder)    at
>   ProjectX.Startup.InitializeContainer(IApplicationBuilder app)

Comment: Can you post the complete stack trace?

Comment: @Steven Stack trace added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the following line:

```
services.AddMvcCore();
```

To:

```
services.AddMvc();
```

Simple Injector's `RegisterMvcViewComponent` method requires the `IViewComponentDescriptorProvider` abstraction to be registered in the ASP.NET Core configuration system. The extension method uses the `IViewComponentDescriptorProvider` to find out which view components it needs to register. The `AddMvcCore()` extension method you are calling however, does not register this `IViewComponentDescriptorProvider`, since the `AddMvcCore` method only registers some basic functionality; it omits view specific stuff. The `AddMvc()` extension method on the other hand, initializes the whole package including view related stuff such as the `IViewComponentDescriptorProvider`.

If you're not interested in view components, you can also omit the call to `RegisterMvcViewComponents()`.

Comment: Your solution fixed the problem. I just started learning .NET Core today, so I didn't really know what I was doing when I installed the MVC Core package instead of the one I needed :-)

Comment: @Kapol I just made an improvement in the integration package. The next release will throw an exception with a messahe that will better explain the problem and how to solve this issue.